# What is the Regex to match a string (only alphabets of maximum length 20 and minimum 1) followed by : and a six digit number.

Tags: html, regex

My regular expression should match the strings of following formats.

a:123456, sdfsdf:765756, dskjsdkfjh: 200000 etc.

Comment: What flavour of Regex are you using?

Comment: Im doing html5 validations in my rails application and one of my text fields need to be of the above format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[a-zA-Z]{1,20}:\d{6}
```

You can try this.